# css scrollbar top and bottom corner not changing

Tags: html, css

[image]

```
   ul.list_view::-webkit-scrollbar {
background: lightyellow;
width: 12px;
   }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px #57c5a0;
 border-radius: 10px;
}
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 border-radius: 10px;
 background:#57c5a0;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px #000000;
}
```

Hi.This is the code for customizing my scrollbar.As you can see in top corner,and also in bottom corner of the scrollbar, there is still a white space..I don't know how to make it disappear.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not white, but lightyellow as specified in your css. You simply need to change the background from `lightyellow` to `transparent`.

```
ul::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background: transparent;
}
```

If you're looking to have a completely transparent track, also remove the box-shadow from `::-webkit-scrollbar-track`.

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you, sir!!

Answer (score 0):

You can learn in-detail about custom webkit scrollbars here

SAMPLE

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 10px;
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

```html
<br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

[image]

[Source](https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. Remove the `-webkit-box-shadow` from `webkit-scrollbar-track`.

```css
body {
  min-height: 1000px;
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: lightyellow;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #57c5a0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```